# My crontab only likes five asterisks (timezone related?)

Tags: cron, timezone

I have a problem with a user's crontab.

Crontab refuses to run any job unless it's scheduled to run every minute (* * * * *).

An soon as you edit the task to run, say, on minute 15 of every hour, it fails to run.

This runs ok every minute:

```
* * * * * touch /tmp/test01
```

This fails to run on minute 15 of every hour. It just won't run.

```
15 * * * * touch /tmp/test02
```

- What's causing this?
- How can it be solved?

OS is RedHat 4.

I always edit the cron with `crontab -e` and `EDITOR` is set to vi. I've changed back and forth between `15 * * * *` (minute can change) and `* * * * *` and the result is the same. It only likes five asterisks.

**HUGE EDIT:**

I followed **@shane-h** 's question and tested for `*/2 * * * *` (every other minute) and it worked! Then I discovered something revealing:

I had made a test with this string `37 * * * * touch /tmp/prueba_777777`

To my surprise the thing actually ran but look at the date of the file:

-rw-r--r--  1 orashut dba     0 Aug  8 08:07 prueba_777777

Recently the server was set to the new Venezuela TimeZone, which is now -04:00, but used to be -04:30.

Whem you run the date command it shows the correct date. When you create a file, the file date in the FS is correct. But somehow cron jobs are running 30 minutes earlier. That's why when I scheduled a job for some minutes in the future it didn't work, because to the cron daemon that time had already passed. If I waited almost an hour it would have run at exactly minutes-30. That's why the touched file is 30 minutes earlier that the schedule's 37.

So the question now is:

It's evident that the cron daemon is working with the old timezone while the rest of the server is working with the new timezone.

How can I fix the cron daemon's understanding of the new timezone?

Comment: How was the `crontab` file edited?  If via `vi` or similar then `cron` won't necessarily have picked up the change.  Use `crontab -e` (or if as root, `crontab -u username -e`) to edit the file.

Comment: @StephenHarris I edited the crontab with `crontab -e`. I've done many other changes like changing the file to be touched and it's effectively picking up the changes. When I changed it back from `15 * * * *` to `* * * * *` it picks up the change and runs every minute. I only edit the cron with the command `crontab -e`.

Comment: have you check /var/log/messages ?

Comment: @Rahul No. No error at all. No message in mail.  It only likes five asterisks. And the task I'm testing is a simple touch. As long as you give it the five asterisks it likes, the cron happily runs the touch every minute. But if you schedule to a minute in the future and wait until that minute nothing happens, no error, no mail, nada. It's five asterisks or nothing.

Comment: There is some kind of time adjust based on a ntp server? If there is, try to disable everything related to it temporary, and see if cron work now.

Comment: Do you see anything interesting in /var/log/cron?

Comment: Does `date` show the right time (in particular the correct minute)?

Comment: @roaima Yes, it does show the right time. In fact when you schedule the task to run every single minute it runs in the exact moment the clock changes to the minute.

Comment: Ok. Just needed to check. You don't seem to be doing anything obviously wrong, so this is a really interesting question :-)

Comment: If you schedule to **two** minutes or more in the future, does the job run? (There are some versions of cron that require one minute to pick up a job: if you set up a `15 * * * *` job at hh:14:ss then it won't be enabled until after hh:15, so it won't run until (hh+1):15.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a specific answer, but here is how i would go about troubleshooting this:

1. Try more combinations to find another working expression. How about: `*/2 * * * *` (every other minute), or `* */2 * * *` (every minute, every other hour). It would be interesting to establish that any *relative* expression works while fixed expressions do not.
2. When you save, do you see the confirmation message "New crontab installed?" (or something similar)
3. Can you do a `crontab -l` to see your message?
4. Is this a user crontab or system crontab?
5. Do you see messages in syslog? If you add a second, `* * * * *` cron you should see that every minute, and if you add the every-other-minute variant, can you see in syslog just the more frequent job?
6. Can you configure a working `at` command?
7. When you have this figured out, I would suggest using a service I built, https://cronitor.io to keep an eye on your important jobs. It's free for a developer to monitor one job and there are paid plans for business use. I had become too much of an expert cron debugger over the years and knew that if I needed a solution to monitor my important jobs other people probably did too.

---

<sup>from comments:</sup>

Cron uses the same system timezone for kicking-off jobs, so I would try just resetting that:

1. Set your timezone again, just to be thorough: on Red Hat use `redhat-config-date`
2. Restart the cron daemon. I think on your OS version: `/etc/init.d/crond restart`

Comment: I tried the every two minutes option and it worked! In the other hand I just discovered something, I'll update the answer. Stay tuned.

Comment: I made an EDIT no the question. Problem seems to be timezone-related. Please read and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Cron uses the same system timezone for kicking-off jobs, so I would try just resetting that: 
1. Set your timezone again, just to be thorough: on redhat use `redhat-config-date`

2. Restart the cron daemon. I think on your os version: `/etc/init.d/crond restart`

Answer (score 2):

> So the question now is:
>
> It's evident that the cron daemon is working with the old timezone while the rest of the server is working with the new timezone.
>
> How can I fix the cron daemon's understanding of the new timezone?

My guess is the a timezone data update package has been installed (`tzdata` RPM or similar) but the server has not been rebooted and the `crond` daemon has not been restarted after the update, so `crond` is still using the old timezone data it loaded when it was originally started.

If that is the problem, then restarting the daemon should fix the problem, as Shane H commented: `service crond restart` or `/etc/init.d/crond restart` should do it. You should also consider restarting any other long-running system daemons that may record timestamps, like `sendmail`.